How to Use PyRevit CLI to Run Python Scripts Without Opening Revit?
I'm currently working on automating some tasks using PyRevit CLI and the Revit API. My goal is to run Python scripts without actually opening the Revit GUI.
Specifically, I've written a simple script to open an IFC file and save it as an RVT file. Here's the script:
import clr
import math
clr.AddReference('RevitAPI')
clr.AddReference('RevitAPIUI')

from Autodesk.Revit.DB import *
from Autodesk.Revit.DB.Architecture import *
from Autodesk.Revit.DB.Analysis import *

app = __revit__.Application

ifc_doc = app.OpenIFCDocument('Room.ifc')
print("Open")
save_options = SaveAsOptions()
save_options.OverwriteExistingFile = True

ifc_doc.SaveAs('output_room.rvt', save_options)
print("Saved")


When I run this script with the command pyrevit run script.py "revitproject.rvt", Revit opens and closes again, displaying information about the execution ID, product, clone, engine, script, working directory, journal file, manifest file, and log file. Without actually converting the files as expected.
I'm looking for guidance on how to correctly use the PyRevit CLI to achieve my goal. Are there any specific resources, documentation, or tutorials that could help with this?

The Revit API is completely event driven. You cannot successfully make calls to the Revit API without a valid Revit API context, and such a context is only provided within the event handler of the events defined by the Revit API. So, your code cannot successfully execute. Please take a look at the The Building Coder getting started material or read the official Developers Guide on implementing a Revit API add-in, and the numerous articles about Idling and External Events for Modeless Access and Driving Revit from Outside.

Thank you for your answer!
I was able to execute my code by doing the following:

Create a pyrevit extension
Run the extension as pyrevit run "path_to_extensio_script.py" "buffer_file.rvt"
Here we've to note that, provide complete path to the extension script file including all parent directories in order for the extension to run properly.


I assume a Revit session is running somewhere i the system, though, isn't it?

Using pyrevit this way fires up revit, runs the process and shuts it down. I need to edit my question a bit, I am OK with the revit GUI popping up, earlier I wasn't getting the desired output files. The method I've mentioned in the question simply did noting, except for creating a session and terminating it.
